# Compress PDF content with Zopfli GZIP Compression

Tags: itext, pdfbox

I wanted to do the following for PDF Compression

1. Extract text from PDF
2. Use Zopfli for efficient gzip compression of Text
3. Insert the compressed text into PDF

Is this feasible using PDFBox or iText

Comment: More to the point, you want to (re)compress content streams with Zopfli because that is the type of pdf entities which contain text and can be compressed. This now might indeed be interesting to do.

Comment: Yes... As per my testing on large number of documents, Zopfli provides approx. 10% additional compression for GZIP as compared to normal linux utility. Hence, the process will be as follows

Comment: 1) Decompress text from PDF (2) Compress the text with Zopfli gzip compression (3) Embed the compressed content back to PDF

Comment: "Under default settings, the output of Zopfli is typically 3–8% smaller than zlib's maximum compression, but takes around 80 times longer". Is that really worth it?

Comment: I guess for archiving purposes it could be worth it.

Comment: i understand 80 times longer. But, if we need to send same PDF to more then 10K users then it is worth

Comment: For PDFBox, a good starting point would be the `WriteDecodedDoc.java` tool. For the streams that are encoded with the Flate filter only, read the content, recompress it and write it with `stream.createRawOutputStream()` instead of `stream.createOutputStream()`. Remove the line `stream.removeItem(COSName.FILTER);` and add a check for the filter.